# What is the meaning of "to" in the following sentence?

Tags: prepositions

What is the meaning of "to " in the sentence, "He is incompetent to manage the hotel"? What is the situation?

Dose it mean "Because he is incompetent, he can not manage the hotel" or "Although He is incompetent, he is managing the hotel" or "Because he is incompetent, he does not manage the hotel" or "Because he is incompetent, he should not manage the hotel" ?

Comment: This is not a grammatical English sentence. Where did you find it?

Comment: I find it at english-korean dictionary of LINGOES. LINGOES is the dictionary program.

Comment: Whenever I see an English sentence, I do not always know clearly what the sentence represents. The English grammar books are really too unkind to give an example of what the English sentences are exactly representing.

Comment: @Catija - Why do you think "He is incompetent to manage the hotel" is not grammatical?  I can find plenty of examples of that structure.

Comment: Indeed, I do not know for certain what circumstances, such as to or as written in English sentences, are being used. Now I am using English using Google Translator.

Comment: According to depending on the presence or absence of the preposition I do not know the true meaning of these prepositions or adverbs in English sentences that use as, for, in, and into. etc.

Comment: @stangdon This form doesn't align with any uses I have seen. Maybe a transitive/intransitive thing? It just doesn't compute. "He was incompetent and could not manage the hotel." Is fine but this use isn't one I ever see.

Comment: The point of my question is in what circumstances the english sentence can be used. I have created a situation where the English sentence can be used.

Comment: For example, Tom is the president of a hotel. But Tom is incompetent. Jenny thinks that Tom does not fit the hotel president. Can Jenny say "He is incompetent to manage the hotel" in such a situation?

Comment: For example, Tom is not the president of a hotel. But Tom is incompetent. Jenny thinks that Tom does not fit to be the hotel president. Can Jenny say "He is incompetent to manage the hotel" in such a situation?

Comment: @Catija - The most common usage is "incompetent to stand trial", but here's [*she is fundamentally incompetent to be its leader*](http://thehill.com/blogs/floor-action/senate/318198-franken-devos-fundamentally-incompetent-to-lead-education-dept), here's [*an employee who is incompetent to carry out its duties*](https://www.aol.com/article/2010/11/22/peter-principle-promotion/19720110/), here's [*he is incompetent to hold a job*](http://postoncourts.blog.palmbeachpost.com/2016/10/11/boca-attorney-asks-pbc-judge-to-declare-trump-incompetent/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A phrase formed by "to" + infinitive and placed after an adjective usually refers to the activity or area in which a certain person (or object) shows a certain property or feature.

It is not always clear whether the subject performs that activity or acts in that area. "He is incompetent (= not qualified) to manage the hotel" may mean:

a) He is incompetent and, being like that, he is not ready to manage the hotel.

b) He is the manager of the hotel but, being incompetent, he does not deserve to hold that position.

Comment: I have thought that To+infinitive represents the future, and the gerund represents the past and the present. If the To-infinitive is irrelevant to the tense, can I use the gerund at the To-infinitive position?  For examples, "He is incompetent  to manage the hotel" = "He is incompetent managing the hotel" ?

Comment: Using Google Translator, the two sentences (1. He is incompetent to manage the hotel 2. He is incompetent managing the hotel) translates to the same meaning. can I use the gerund at the To-infinitive position?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are making it too complicated.  **He is incompetent to manage the hotel** simply means that he is [*incompetent*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incompetent) - that is, *not qualified*, or *does not possess the necessary abilities* - for the purpose of managing the hotel.  **Incompetent to X** is kind of a stock phrase that means "does not have the necessary abilities to do *X*".

The sentence implies nothing about whether he is currently managing the hotel or not.

Comment: I have thought that To+infinitive represents the future, and the gerund represents the past and the present. If the To-infinitive is irrelevant to the tense, can I use the gerund at the To-infinitive position? For examples, "He is incompetent to manage the hotel" = "He is incompetent managing the hotel" ?

Comment: Using Google Translator, the two sentences (1. He is incompetent to manage the hotel  2. He is incompetent managing the hotel)  translates to the same meaning.  can I use the gerund at the To-infinitive position?

Comment: The to-infinitive does not represent the future in this case.  You *can* use the gerund, but it doesn't sound as fluent.  Also, "managing the hotel" implies that he is managing the hotel right now, and the original sentence does not imply that.   As I said, "competent to *X*" is the standard phrase, so you should use it.  Don't trust Google Translate too much; it is not always accurate.